# If $ n \in \mathbb{N} $, then does the Reynolds operator of $ \mathbb{G}_{m}^{n} $ commute with the Frobenius endomorphism?

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, classical-invariant-theory, frobenius-map

If $ n \in \mathbb{N} $, then $ \mathbb{G}_{m}^{n} $ is linearly reductive.  Let $ \beta: \mathbb{G}_{m}^{n} \to \operatorname{GL}(\mathbf{V}) $ where $ \mathbf{V} $ is a vector space over an algebraically closed field $ k $.  The representation $ \beta $ corresponds to an action $ \beta: \mathbb{G}_{m}^{n} \times \mathbf{V} \to \mathbf{V} $.  If we denote the affine coordinate ring of $ \mathbb{G}_{m}^{n} $ by $ k[\mathbb{G}_{m}^{n}] $, then the co-action $ \beta^{\sharp}: \operatorname{Sym}(\mathbf{V}^{\ast}) \to \operatorname{Sym}(\mathbf{V}^{\ast})\otimes_{k} k[\mathbb{G}_{m}^{n}] $.

If $ \mathbf{V} $ is a vector space over an algebraically closed field $ k $ of positive characteristic, then does the Frobenius endomorphism $ F: \operatorname{Sym}(\mathbf{V}^{\ast}) \to \operatorname{Sym}(\mathbf{V}^{\ast}) $ commute with the Reynolds operator $ R_{\mathbb{G}_{m}^{n}}: \operatorname{Sym}(\mathbf{V}^{\ast}) \to \operatorname{Sym}(\mathbf{V}^{\ast})^{\mathbb{G}_{m}^{n}} $?

Comment: The Frobenius endomorphism of what? We have a group, a vector space and a representation.

Comment: Thank you @WilberdvanderKallen.  I hope I have made appropriate corrections.

Comment: What is $F$ when $V$ is one dimensional? The symmetric algebra is then a polynomial ring $k[t]$. Does $F$ act on $k$? On $t$? By the way, it is much better to define the Reynolds operator on $V$, rather than on a ring.